# Evitar volver a la pantalla anterior

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, activity

Estoy haciendo un juego en Android Studio y en un determinado momento me voy hacia otra pantalla.
Como puedo digamos "bloquearla" esa nueva pantalla para evitar volver atras?
Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es evitar que se regrese a la pantalla anterior al pulsar el botón atrás, sobrecarga el evento [onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) de tu [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
  //En caso de querer permitir volver atrás usa esta llamada:
  super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Para volver atrás sin que haya necesidad de pulsar el botón puedes usar [finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()).

Comment: De acuerdo. Pero de que sirve sobrecargarlo?

Comment: Por defecto super.onBackPressed() ejecuta finish(), finalizando la pantalla actual y volviendo a la pantalla anterior. Si [sobrecargas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herencia_(informática)) la función y la dejas en blanco, se evita que al pulsar el botón anterior se vuelva.